# What is the distribution of completed parts by a given machine after t minutes in SimPy's Machine Shop example?

Tags: distributions, stochastic-processes, discrete-time

## Question

You can read the [Machine Shop](https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/machine_shop.html) example in the [SimPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SimPy) documentation, however I have tried to put it into its mathematical description below so that reading [Python](https://www.python.org/) is not necessary.

Suppose a workshop with $n$ [identical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables) machines.

Any machine is either working or broken, and each machine begins in the working state in the initial conditions. A working machine has a time-to-broken in minutes of $\tau_{\text{break}} \sim \text{Exponential}\left( \lambda_{\text{break}} \right)$.

When a machine breaks, a request to the repairman is instantly made. If the repairman isn't busy, then they immediately begin repairing the machine. It takes exactly $\tau_{\text{repair}}$ minutes for the repairman to fix a machine. The repairman can only repair one machine at a time. If the repairman is already working on a machine then the recently-broken machine must wait its turn to be fixed (i.e. first-come-first-serve or first-in-first-out (FIFO)).

While a machine is working it produces parts. Each part takes $\tau_{\text{part}}$ minutes to be completed where $\tau_{\text{part}} \sim \text{TruncatedNormal} \left( \mu_{\text{part}}, \sigma_{\text{part}}, 0, \infty \right)$. A machine which is broken (including when it is being repaired) does not produce parts. However, when a machine is repaired it picks up exactly where it left off.

> Note that the SimPy documentation uses a normal distribution instead of a truncated normal distribution. This results in errors when negative numbers are sampled. I have [raised this issue](https://gitlab.com/team-simpy/simpy/-/issues/157) on the developer's GitLab. I have just chosen a similar distribution instead.

Assume that time is discrete and progresses on a non-negative integer scale of minutes. So if a part requires 10.2 minutes, it will actually be considered completed once 11 minutes have elapsed. This entails a ceiling round on the completion time of parts, $\text{ceil}(\tau_{\text{part}})$. This change of variables is accomplished by integrating the intervals between non-negative integers in the support of the truncated normal distribution above.

**For given number of minutes $t$ since the initial condition, what is the distribution of completed parts by a given machine?**

---

## My Thoughts

Here is what I've surmised. This is a discrete stochastic process. It has a distribution of completed parts by a given machine for any discrete time $t$. Although it isn't a stationary distribution, there are aspects of the problem that are well-behaved. For example, the part-completion and time-to-break are stationary. Since the machines are identical in their statistical properties and begin in identical states, I expect the distribution of parts completed by a given machine to be the same as any other machine at some time $t$. Something which seems less-nice about the problem is the fact that the state transitions of the machines are not entirely independent from each other even though they are identical due to the fact that sometimes one machine will wait for another to be repaired. I'm not sure how to procedure with that aspect.

While I'm not sure how to get the distribution, it occurred to me that there is a distribution that [stochastically dominates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance) the distribution of interest. This train of thought begins with the fact that $\tau_{\text{part}}$ is stationary. If the machines never broke, then I suspect the number of parts produced by a machine in $t$ minutes would be given by $\text{floor} \left(\frac{t}{\tau_{\text{part}}} \right)$. I have not worked out this change of variables. Why I think it dominates the true distribution is because everything having to do with breaking and being repaired only takes time away from producing parts (i.e. there is a sort of monotonicity condition that applies).

Running the simulation in the docs 10k times, I've noticed that it follows what appears to be a normal distribution. This suggests that something like a [CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) is at least approximately satisfied. Here is a histogram of the number of parts manufactured by a machine.

[image]

It occurred to me that it is theoretically possible for two machines to break at the exact same time, albeit with probability zero. If it matters, we can assume that a fixed total order on the machines used to resolve any such clashes.